# How do you sort a list of users with Facebook friends at the top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'd like to be able to return a list of users from my application with the current user's Facebook friends listed first. I see there are ways to query the Graph API to return a user's friends who use an application, but I want to be able to show a list of users who have taken a specific action on my site and sort them with FB friends listed first, so any time I am displaying a list of users I am able to do this sorting.

The best example of this I have seen is on meetup.com. They do this when showing a list of people who are attending a meetup. Here's an example:

[image: An example of how Meetup sorts a user list with FB friends first]

I don't know that it will make any difference to anyone, but it is a Rails app and I am using OmniAuth to do the authentication through Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort on friend status because there is no friend status column. You can't do any complex SQL operations joining or unioning the *friends* table with another table because FQL doesn't support these operations. The best you can do is identify who the friends are via a separate query...

```
SELECT uid FROM friend WHERE uid IN (...ALL USER IDs...)
```

All the *uid*'s returned from that query will be a subset of your full list, including only those whom are friends.

***Additional Info***:

The Meetup app is...

1. First querying it's local database to generate a list of participants. (lets call the result [`participants`] )
2. Then, they perform a query on the facebook *friend* database to determine which of those [`participants`] are friends. (lets call the result [`participating_friends`] )

   **SELECT uid FROM friend WHERE uid IN ([`participants`])**
3. They also store that list of [`participating_friends`] uid's in their local database. One column is the user's id (*uid*) and the other is their friend's uid (*friendid*).
4. Finally, to determine *friends of friends* they query their local friends database (from 3) with a query like:

   **SELECT *friendid* FROM local_friends WHERE *uid* IN ([`participating_friends`])**

**UPDATE**: In retrospect, Meetup might be casting an even wider net as follows:

The Meetup app is...

1. First querying it's local database to generate a list of participants. (lets call the result [`participants`] )
2. Then, they perform a query on the facebook *friend* database to determine which of those [`participants`] are friends. (lets call the result [`participating_friends`] )

   **SELECT uid FROM friend WHERE uid IN ([`participants`])**
3. Determining **all** friends of the app user who are also app users and store the result in a local database, saving *uid*'s and associated *friendid*'s.

   **SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user**
4. Finally, to determine *friends of friends*, calculate the new set:

   [`participants_not_friends`] = [`participants`] - [`participating_friends`].

   Then query the local friends database (from 3) with a query like:

   **SELECT *friendid* FROM local_friends WHERE *uid* IN ([`participants_not_friends`])**

Comment: yeah, they're basically taking the list of attendees, the list of friends and comparing the two

Comment: this answer was and is correct. If you're down-voting maybe you should explain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a list of friends for each user. Here is how I would do it.

At registration, if a user registers with Facebook, you store their ID in the database.

When an authenticated user views one of your records, issue this FQL query via the API:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square, mutual_friend_count FROM user 
 WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
   AND is_app_user 
 ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC
```

This will give you back other users of your app who are friends with the current user ordered by the mutual friend count between your app user and each friend (assuming closer friends have greater numbers of mutual friends).

You can compare this list against any other metric in your database by comparing the result of this query with the stored Facebook ids in your db.

Showing friends of friends is a trickier proposition. If you try this query:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN 
 (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 1)
```

It throws a permission error. Facebook doesn't let you get friends of friends.

If it's important to your app, you could get around this by caching each of your app user's most recent friend list each time they login (or on a schedule if you also asked for an extended access token), and querying this table to see if there are friends in common with all the user's friends. You'll need to take a close look at the TOS to see how legal this is.